# Насколько необходим Viewport в верстке под мобильные устройства?

Tags: css, вёрстка, firefox, mobile, viewport

Есть страница, свёрстанная с использованием медиа-запросов:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  ...
}
```

В вертикальном положении устройства страница отображается как контент для мобильного устройства, в горизонтальном - как полноценный сайт. Viewport не использую, в мобильном варианте всё отображается хорошо под браузером Chrome и других на его базе. В стилях для медиа-запроса используются значения, заданные посредством `vw`.

Проблемы две:

1. Мобильный Firefox и браузеры, созданные на его основе, не вписывают страницу в границы экрана устройства.
2. Добавление `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />` ломает вёрстку - элементы отображаются с очень высоким масштабом (и мелкими элементами интерфейса). Попытка уменьшить начальный масштаб приводит к тому, что он отображается уменьшенным и в горизонтальном положении устройства тоже. При этом проблема с отображением под Firefox не была решена.

Прошу совета:

1. Насколько необходим viewport сам по себе?
2. Как решить проблему с заходящим за экран устройства контентом под Firefox и связано ли решение проблемы с указанием viewport?

Comment: чтобы все хорошо отображалось и на ПК и на мобильных, лучше сразу начинать верстать с `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`